# Undefined reference linker error when implementing function declared in anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

When defining a function signature in an anonymous namespace within a .hpp, is it valid to place the implementation of that function within the .cpp? When I do so I get an undefined reference error.

Example:

```
//hpp
#ifndef __BAR_HPP_
#define __BAR_HPP_
namespace foo
{
   namespace 
   {
       struct Bar
       {
           void func();
       };
   }
}
#endif

//cpp  
using foo;

void Bar::func()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Why would you use an anonymous namespace like that? And names like `__BAR_HPP_` which contain a double underscore, or names that begin with an underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved for the C++ implementation.

Comment: I used it like this because the function func() is only pertinent to the Bar class.

Comment: Well, make it a private function of Bar. Or put it in an anonymous namespace in the Bar implementation file.

Comment: Oddly, this seems to work for me... *although* I do need to change 'using foo' to 'using namespace foo'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of this:

```
namespace foo
{
    struct Bar
    {
        void func();
    };
}
void Bar::func() { /*impl...*/ }
```

Your code doesn't work for the same reason this code doesn't -- the definition is being provided in the wrong scope. What's needed is:

```
void foo::Bar::func() { /*impl...*/ }
```

But what do you put in place of `foo::` to refer to the name of an anonymous namespace? It doesn't have one.

Bottom line: it's not possible to declare something inside of an anonymous namespace then define it elsewhere, as no mechanism exists for specifying the proper scope.